# Change image src using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, onmouseover, image-loading

I want to slide show of image on mouse over(all images in json array) and i need to change only img src. In this array image are in different size.Like some are 256X256 and some are 436x436.

but for large image its giving an error on firefox
"Image corrupt or truncated: http://localhost/product/9cca72417668f1d813dcbc815a8ddb63.jpg"

i have a following code :

```
jQuery('.sales-product-images').on('mouseover',function(){
var counter = 0;
var selector = jQuery(this);
var pd_id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
var imageArray = jQuery.parseJSON(images);
var product_images= imageArray[pd_id];
default_image = product_images[product_images.length - 1];
timer = setInterval(function() {
  selector.fadeOut("slow",
  function () {
    if (counter === product_images.length) {
      counter = 0;
    }

    selector.attr('src', image_path_front + 'product/' + product_images[counter]);
      selector.show();
      counter = counter+ 1;
    });

  });

}, 2300);
```

I want show another image if one fully loaded or if not possible then Can i show loading image until other image not loaded..
Please help me.

Comment: Does it work under other browsers ?

Comment: Then use good image which is not corrupted !

Comment: How big is the image, in terms of its filesize?

Comment: @ jQuery.PHP.Magento.com images are not currupted but before showing next image(i m using set interval for looping)..large image was not able to load for that time and i cant increase the time.

Comment: @Brewal its working for chrome 28.0.1500.52 linux..but error on all other browser that image is truncated only for large images